# USB adapters for simultaneous access to multiple MicroSD cards

Tags: microsd

I'm looking for a compact MicroSD card adapter with multiple slots to enable simultaneous access to at least two (preferrably more) MicroSD cards.  In essence: multiple MicroSD card readers in a single device.  The idea is to access multiple large-capacity cards at the same time using a single device rather than using a USB switch with separate adapters.

Here is an example of an adapter than can read and write from two cards simultaneously: [https://www.amazon.com/Cateck-USB3-0-4-Slot-Reader-Micro/dp/B01J5651NA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01J5651NA)

Comment: Add 2 microsd to TF adapters and now your device can support 4 total

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple adapters
[https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4UB5132701&cm_re=micro_sdhc_usb_adapter-*-9SIA4UB5132701-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4UB5132701&cm_re=micro_sdhc_usb_adapter-_-9SIA4UB5132701-_-Product)

[https://www.amazon.com/Eye-Fi-Compact-Adapter-Professional-Digital/dp/B001DKO7R8/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1514840011&sr=8-4&keywords=micro+sd+to+compact+flash+adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DKO7R8)

Now you have a device with 1. MicroSD, 2. microsd to sd to compact flash,3. microsd to TF.  More adapter probably exist.

How about this it accepts 10 sd cards.

[https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA86V4U72871&cm_re=sd_10-*-9SIA86V4U72871-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA86V4U72871&cm_re=sd_10-_-9SIA86V4U72871-_-Product)

You could add a SATA to USB adapter to this.